# How to make SKSpritekit nodes bounce off each other

Tags: sprite-kit

I know how to set up the physic attributes but i don't know what code i need to make them bounce off each other realistically, like the balls on a pool table. I have my didBeginContact method ready,

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact*)contact
{
uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);
if (collision == (gearCategory | gear1Category)) {
    [
}
}
```

but  i have no idea what code i need in it, can anyone with good math and vectoring skills help me out?

Comment: The didBeginContact method is only a delegate, i.e. a notifier about two bodies coming into contact with each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a VERY easy task in sprite kit.

```
//Add to top of scene
static const uint32_t spriteCategory =  0x1 << 0;

//declare when creating sprite
sprite.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = spriteCategory;
sprite.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = spriteCategory;
```

What this does is set a sprite to collide with all sprites given the spriteCategory as their categoryBitMask.  You can have your sprite set to collide with multiple different categoryBitMasks using the following code.

```
sprite.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = spriteCategory|otherCategory|anotherCategory;
```

Did begin contact is used to execute some code when the nodes touch.  You would use the contactTestBitMask property to detect when items touch.  collisionBitMask automatically handles collisions for you !!!

I have attached a link that has an entire section devoted to collision and contact.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners

Comment: Is there a way to make it so that they never exceed a certain speed. At the moment, they just keep gaining speed bouncing off each other and eventually fly off the screen.

Comment: sprite.physicsBody.restitution = 0; Play with this number, it is the "bounciness" property.

Comment: Please mark this as answered if your question was... answered :)